# How to use Spanish Unicode characters while wrapping text in a longtabu cell

Tags: longtable, tabu, spanish

Some time ago i referred to this stack exchange to solve the problem of wrapping long text in a longtabu cell. The provided solution worked, but now my requirements have changed to having to be able to print Spanish characters as well as English. So the wrap function no longer works. i was wondering how to accomplish this? im able to print Spanish characters outside the wrap function as shown in the example. Thanks!

```
\documentclass[6pt]{extarticle}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Package Inclusions %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{longtable, tabu}
\usepackage{xparse} % used for \ExplSyntaxOn

%used to print Spanish characters in the text
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[english,spanish]{babel}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% CONFIGURATIONS  %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\tabulinesep=5mm % used to set the space between bottem and top of cell in a longtabu using option m in column definition

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Custom Commands %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\separator}{ }
 {
  \mode_if_math:TF { \allowbreak } { \- }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\wrap}{ m } % use this command to wrap text \wrap{text goes here}
 {
  \mathers_wrap:n { #1 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l_mathers_input_seq
\seq_new:N \l_mathers_output_seq
\seq_new:N \l_mathers_temp_seq

\cs_new_protected:Npn \mathers_wrap:n #1
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l_mathers_output_seq
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_mathers_input_seq { ~ } { #1 }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_mathers_input_seq
   {
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_mathers_temp_seq { } { ##1 }
    \seq_put_right:Nx \l_mathers_output_seq
     { \seq_use:Nn \l_mathers_temp_seq { \separator } }
   }
  \seq_use:Nn \l_mathers_output_seq { ~ }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Report Start %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

Spanish Characters: á, é, í, ó, ú, ü, ñ, ¿, ¡

\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth {
    |X[1,l,m]|
    X[1,l,m]|
    X[1,l,m]|
    }
    \hline
    \wrap{á tttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt} &
    \wrap{ttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt} &
    \wrap{ttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt} 
    \\\hline
    \wrap{ttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt} &
    \wrap{ttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt} &
    \wrap{ttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt} 
    \\\hline
    \wrap{ttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt} &
    \wrap{ttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt} &
    \wrap{ttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt} 
    \\\hline
\end{longtabu}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! A failing example would be better.

Comment: Hey, So i added a Spanish character in the wrap function inside the longtabu. the code is now failing. thanks

Comment: The easiest workaround is to type the special characters inside braces, like `S{á}nchez`. This only in the argument to `\wrap`, of course.

Comment: hmmm, i tried using: \wrap{{á} tttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt} & but it did not work

Comment: And `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` (`utf8x` isn't really recommended). A single letter (separated from the rest by spaces, or at the beginning or end) needs two sets of braces.

Comment: tried that just now, same error. ill add the error to the question

Comment: k so, \wrap{{{á}} tttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt} &  works. So i assume it will be alot more difficult to allow them automatically?

Comment: doed, im not sure what your referring to. sorry

Comment: It's really more difficult; a much slower routine is needed to cope with multibyte characters. On the other hand, it should work flawlessly with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX (with `fontspec` and (Open|True)Type fonts).

Comment: Steve, I removed the comment, because I assumed `\wrap{}{}{á` was possible, since its compilation was fine, but it doesn't work. I was just looking at the compilation, not the final document.

Comment: So the solution to wrap the spanish in {{}} worked, it was a bit more work for me, but thats ok. Im using Java/Velocity to generate these reports, so i built some helper classes to take care of this. seems to all be working now. egreg if you want, you can write an answer with what you stated above and i can accept as answer. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Unicode characters the routine to be used is more complex. This seems to work, at least for the characters you need. Please, don't use `utf8x`.

```
\documentclass[6pt]{extarticle}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Package Inclusions %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{longtable, tabu}
\usepackage{xparse} % used for \ExplSyntaxOn

%used to print Spanish characters in the text
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[english,spanish]{babel}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% CONFIGURATIONS  %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\tabulinesep=5mm % used to set the space between bottem and top of cell in a longtabu using option m in column definition

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Custom Commands %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\separator}{ }
 {
  \mode_if_math:TF { \allowbreak } { \- }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\wrap}{ m } % use this command to wrap text \wrap{text goes here}
 {
  \mathers_wrap:n { #1 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l_mathers_input_seq
\seq_new:N \l_mathers_output_seq
\seq_new:N \l_mathers_temp_seq
\tl_new:N \l_mathers_word_seq

\cs_new_protected:Npn \mathers_wrap:n #1
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l_mathers_output_seq
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_mathers_input_seq { ~ } { #1 }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_mathers_input_seq
   {
    \mathers_scan_word:n { ##1 }
   }
  \seq_use:Nn \l_mathers_output_seq { ~ }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \mathers_scan_word:n #1
 {
  \tl_clear:N \l_mathers_word_tl
  \__mathers_scan_word_aux: #1 \q_stop
  \seq_put_right:NV \l_mathers_output_seq \l_mathers_word_tl
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mathers_scan_word_aux:
 {
  \peek_meaning:NTF { \q_stop }
   {
    \use_none:n
   }
   {
    \peek_meaning:NTF ^^c3
     { \mathers_eat:NN }
     {
      \peek_meaning:NTF ^^c2
       { \mathers_eat:NN }
       { \mathers_eat:N }
     }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \peek_meaning:NTF { c }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \mathers_eat:NN #1 #2
 { \tl_put_right:Nn \l_mathers_word_tl {#1#2\separator}\__mathers_scan_word_aux: }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \mathers_eat:N #1
 { \tl_put_right:Nn \l_mathers_word_tl {#1\separator}\__mathers_scan_word_aux: }


\ExplSyntaxOff

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Report Start %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

Spanish Characters: á, é, í, ó, ú, ü, ñ, ¿, ¡

\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth {
    |X[1,l,m]|
    X[1,l,m]|
    X[1,l,m]|
    }
    \hline
    \wrap{á éíóúüñ¿¡áé íóúüñ¿¡áé í óúüñ¿¡áéíóúüñ¿¡áéíóúüñ¿¡áéíóúüñ¿¡áéíóúüñ¿¡ é} &
    \wrap{ttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt} &
    \wrap{ttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt} 
    \\\hline
    \wrap{ttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt} &
    \wrap{ttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt} &
    \wrap{ttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt} 
    \\\hline
    \wrap{ttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt} &
    \wrap{ttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt} &
    \wrap{ttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt} 
    \\\hline
\end{longtabu}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Supporting other characters may require more checks with `\peek_meaning:NTF`; these are sufficient for Spanish characters.